# Redis repository and polymorphism don't work together

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data

I have this code :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RedisHash
class Root {
  private Base base;
}

public interface Base {

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Implementor implements Base {
  // ...
}

public class CustomKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {
    private final String prefix;
    
    public SagtKeyspaceConfiguration(String prefix) {
        super();
        
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasSettingsFor(Class<?> type) {
        if (super.hasSettingsFor(type) == false) {
            KeyspaceSettings settings = new KeyspaceSettings(type, prefix + ClassUtils.getUserClass(type).getName());
            addKeyspaceSettings(settings);
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have a `CrudRepository` for the `Root` class which allows me to successfully store objects of that type in Redis.

But when I retrieve an object with a simple `findById`, I get this error:

> Failed to instantiate some.package.name.Base using constructor
> NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments

However, the `_class` attribute is correctly set in Redis for that property:

```
base._class: some.package.name.Implementor
```

Why does it try to instantiate an interface while the actual class is correctly set in the Redis HashMap?

**Edit:**

I tried to create a minimal reproducible example with the same version of spring-data-redis (2.6.4) but it worked...

There must be something else in my project but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was related with the Spring Boot Dev Tools.

Spring Data has this [piece of code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/8b560f96c3ba49e86cfdca57340451330fe25fdf/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/DefaultTypeMapper.java#L138):

```
Class<?> documentsTargetType = getDefaultedTypeToBeUsed(source);

if (documentsTargetType == null) {
    return basicType;
}

Class<T> rawType = basicType.getType();

boolean isMoreConcreteCustomType = (rawType == null)
    || (rawType.isAssignableFrom(documentsTargetType) && !rawType.equals(documentsTargetType));

if (!isMoreConcreteCustomType) {
    return basicType;
}
```

In my case, `documentsTargetType` contained `Implementor` and `basicType` contained `Base`. The `rawType.isAssignableFrom(documentsTargetType)` condition is supposed to return `true`, but it my case it was returning `false`, because `Base` and `Implementor` were loaded by different classloaders because of the Dev Tools.

So this code was returning `Base` instead of `Implementor`.

Problem fixed by removing `spring-boot-devtools` from the project's dependencies.